# Python syntax error when setting variable

Tags: python-3.x, string, syntax

When I try to echo a number with an equals sign, this error happens:

```
    printThis = "=" +str(result)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And I tried to do `print("=" +str(result))`, it does a similar error.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

### EDIT:

```py
elif calc == "base":
    base = int(input('''What base would you like to use?
Available: 2 (binary) 8 (octo) 10 (decimal (normal)) 16 (hex)
Type 2, 8, 10, or 16: '''))
    if base == 2:
        result = bin(input("Type the original number: ")
        printThis = "=" +str(result)
        print(printThis)
```

Comment: Your snippet works for me, so please [edit] your question and add an [mre] that reproduces this error

Comment: @OcasoProtal Edited it, try it now

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis at the end of `result = ...`

Comment: There is a `)` missing, it should be `result = bin(input("Type the original number: "))`

Comment: Thank you @OcasoProtal!   It now works!

Comment: And @Heike ! Thanks both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

close the bracket at the end for the below line in your code

```
result = bin(input("Type the original number: "))
```